Note on max-min algebra?
I am looking for a note or a text for the rules for max-min algebra.
What is a name of course for learning these? I used to see a pdf note online.
Let $a,b,c$ be vectors.
I am looking to prove properties like this:

$\min_{a\in A}a\cdot (b+c) \geq \min_{a\in A}a\cdot b+\min_{a\in A}a\cdot c$.


I don't think there's a specific course for identities like this; I don't think the study of these kinds of inequalities is rich enough for that. You'll learn the tools to prove inequalities like in a real analysis course, and you'll see various similar rules utilised in other pure courses, such as optimisation, convex analysis, approximation theory, and sporadically where such pure principles are used (e.g. game theory).

@TheoBendit Perhaps not worth one course, but definitely worth a few classes.

Possibly of interest: google "max-plus algebra", or the closely related, min-plus algebra There are a variety of expository papers.
